# How to get the difference of two numbers from the input box without page submittal using Codeigniter?

Tags: javascript

I have  three input boxes, of which two are for entering values (any number) and one is for getting results (the difference of the two). How can I get the result without using page submission using Codeigniter?

Comment: retagged, has nothing to do with CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for that.

```
<input type="text" id=first" name="firstInput" />
<input type="text" id="second" name="secondInput" />
<input type="text" id="third" name="thirdInput" />

//jquery
$(document).ready(function() {
  var first = parseInt($("#first").val(), 10);
  var second = parseInt($("#second").val(), 10);
  var thirdVal = first - second;
  $("#third").val('');
  $("#third").val(thirdVal);
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

without exactly knowing how the result is being called you could use on `onblur` on the second number input/ first.

```
<input name="number" id="num_0" type="text" />
<input name="number" id="num_1" type="text" onblur="getResult()" />
<input name="number" id="num_2_result" type="text" />
```

script to get result derived for num_0 and num_1

```
function getResult(){

   var number = document.getElementsByName('number');

   var result = parseInt(number[0].value,10) - parseInt(number[1].value,10);

   // if is a number display reuslt
   if(!isNaN(result)){
      number[2].value = result;
   }
}
```